# How to input external sensor's data for Head tracking in cardboard

Tags: sensors, sensor-fusion

I would like to make cardboard app without android internal sensors and input the external sensor's data for Head Tracking. How do I make that?

Could you give me link or sample code for that?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can see this [repo](https://github.com/raasun/cardboard)

This is decompilated source from cardboard.
Simple way - inherit from cardboard classes and rewrite  sensor listners code.